# How to avoid make running a recipe multiple times for multiple targets?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I run `make all` the below script runs `python ./src/data_preprocess.py` multiple times even when I used the operator `&:` to specify that `${PREPROCESSED}` is a group target, how can I setup the makefile so that `./src/data_preprocess.py` is ran only once?

```
PREPROCESSED := ./data/searches_X_train ./data/searches_X_test 

all: ${PREPROCESSED}

./data/searches.pkl: ./src/data_load.py
    python ./src/data_load.py

${PREPROCESSED} &: ./src/data_preprocess.py
    python ./src/data_preprocess.py
```

Comment: Grouped targets were introduced in GNU make 4.3.  If you don't have that version of GNU make, then what you've defined is a set of single targets plus the single target which is the literal value `&`.  The online documentation describes the latest released version: if you're not building GNU make yourself then you should read the version of the documentation that came with your distribution (or wherever you got your GNU make) to know what's supported by that version.

Comment: My version is GNU Make 3.81 I'll check the new version, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by `MadScientist`, `grouped targets` were introduced in `GNU make 4.3`.

Make version can be checked with `make --version`. And I have an older version as it turns out.